# How to know if the model can smile or talk

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

I've been trying to learn 3d animation. I'm a software developer. I don't have a formal education in animation or about graphics. I found this tool for maya

https://www.animationstudios.com.au/advanced-skeleton

And upon watching the tutorial on the website the tool is super cool. I've read that the blender can also do this. But the problem is I don't know how to make a model. So i will look for models online. But the problem is this. The free models i downloaded online is glued as one. They doesn't have a parts like eye, tongue, mouth, face. So i need to buy a model. But i need to know the requirements before buying a model.

How do i know that the model can blink, smile or talk?

Thank you,

Regards

Comment: I guess this is more like a question on how to buy models for blender rather than a problem you have experienced with the software. But if you want characters with a moth rig you can download it from here - https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters. In sites like Turbosquid, they will provide images showing the entire rig of a character you can spot the mouth rig from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the lips need to be not fused together for a face rig to work properly on the mouth. Otherwise, you'll need to separate the mesh yourself, which can be a pain. Most commercial rigs will not have this problem. Also, if the mouth, teeth, and eyes are not separate objects, they'll be very easy to separate if they have their own vertex groups. Failing that, you can select and isolate by material in the Edit menu. If these things are not stipulated in the details for the figure you're downloading, then you may need to ask the creator specifically.